# How can I make a method compute set union or difference, based on an input parameter?

Tags: c++, vector, set

I want to write a C++ method that lets me either get the union or set difference of two custom set objects.

Each set is represented by a `std::vector<bool>` object and a `std::vector<set>` object. The vector maintains boolean set membership information, and the set contains the indices of the members of each set. The target set is MUCH larger than the source set.

I would like to be able to give a parameter to my method that lets me choose whether to return the union or difference of the sets. Here is (a very cut-down version of) what I have so far:

```
class SetObj{
  public:  
    std::vector<bool> bool_data;
    std::set<int> set_data;

    SetObj(std::vector<bool> bool_input, std::set<int> set_input) :
        bool_data(bool_input), set_data(set_input) {};

    SetObj(std::vector<int> int_input, int num_elements){
        bool_data = std::vector<bool>(num_elements, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < int_input.size(); ++i){
            bool_data[int_input[i]] = true;
            set_data.insert(int_input[i]);
        }
    };
};


void combineSets(const SetObj &src, SetObj &tgt, const bool get_union){

    if (get_union){
        for (auto it=src.set_data.begin(); it!=src.set_data.end(); ++it){
            if (src.bool_data[*it]){
                tgt.bool_data[*it] = true;
            }
            tgt.set_data.insert(*it);
        }
    }
    else{
        for (auto it=src.set_data.begin(); it!=src.set_data.end(); ++it){
            if (src.bool_data[*it]){
                tgt.bool_data[*it] = false;
            }
            tgt.set_data.erase(*it);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works fine for what I want, but it just feels a bit "hackish" as it is basically doing the same thing in both branches of the conditional; its sets the elements of the vector object to true/false and uses the insert/erase methods from `std::set` to update the set object, depending on union or difference.

Is there a way I can get rid of this conditional?

Comment: "Is there a way I can get rid of this conditional?" Probably. But I wouldn't do it because: one optimization of inner loops is to remove conditional branches - especially if they choose the same branch for every element. In this case, the conditional branch is moved to outside and - yes - you get two very similar looking loops in the inside... This is said assuming that optimization of set union/intersection is necessary/intended.

Comment: Changeing: `tgt.bool_data[*it] = get_union;` and `get_union ? tgt.set_data.insert(*it) : tgt.set_data.erase(*it);` actually doesn't eleminate the conditional - it just moves it to another place. So, I would replace the "Probably" by "May be" (or "hardly").

Comment: Thanks. My background is in mathematics and not programming, so I am always worried that my code will be hackish and not the best way to solve a problem. I realised as soon as i posted it that i can remove the conditional inside the loop because `src.bool_data[*it]` will always be `true` if we are iterating through the `std::set` object. But i suppose i was asking if there was a way i could use a variable for the `erase` and `insert` methods, that are determined based on the boolean parameter. But it seems that it is not necessary anyway, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yeah. My last crazy idea was to use a method pointer (pointer to member function) to move the condition for `insert()`/`erase()` outside of the loop. (i.e. conditionally assign address of `set<>::insert()` or `set<>::erase()` to a pointer and call inside the loop via this pointer.) Thereby, I was misleaded by the "identical" calls of `insert()` and `erase()`. Actually, these two methods have multiple signatures but there is no common intersection. Hence there's nothing appropriate which can be called via same method pointer.

Comment: Yeah, and it looks like it is probably too much trouble to go to, in order to avoid just having two similar looking loops in the same method. Hehehe. Thanks again for your help!